# wordpress page permalinks are http but show up as https?

Tags: wordpress, https, permalinks

My page permalinks are http [image: permalink http]

Settings -> Site & Home URL set to http://

but the links all go to https://
It seems all my page permalinks are being rendered as https.

I do not have any redirect rules in my .htaccess that are making this happen.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apps.abc.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /apps.abc.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I'm stumped, been at this for a little while and can't for the life of me figure it out. I know it's going to be something really dumb I did or didn't do, I'm hoping someone can point it out.

Comment: If you go to Settings -> General in the Wordpress admin, is your Site or Home URL set to https:// ?

Comment: @TimMalone No, http